# Ripple effect on TabBarBottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

How to add ripple animation when a tabs is clicked in TabBarBottom. I want ripple effect just like Youtube app
[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Screen's Navigation Options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#Screen-Navigation-Options) to add desired styled `tabBarIcon`

> **tabBarIcon**
>
> React Element or a function that given `{ focused: boolean, tintColor:
>   string }` returns a `React.Element`, to display in tab bar
>
> **tabBarLabel**
>
> Title string of a tab displayed in the tab bar or React Element or a
>   function that given `{ focused: boolean, tintColor: string }` returns
>   a `React.Element`, to display in tab bar. When undefined, scene title
>   is used. To hide, see `tabBarOptions.showLabel` in the previous
>   section.
>
> **tabBarOnPress**
>
> Callback to handle tap events; arguments are the `scene: { route,
>   index }` that was tapped and a `jumpToIndex` method that can perform
>   the navigation for you.

**Example**

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({focuced, tintColor}) => (
        <MyCustomIcon focuced={focuced} tintColor={tintColor} name="Home" />
      )
    })
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({focuced, tintColor}) => (
        <MyCustomIcon focuced={focuced} tintColor={tintColor} name="Notifications" />
      )
    })
  },
});
```

Comment: I dont have any problem with rendering icon. I want the animation effect when the icon is touched just like the gif

Comment: @John thats why you need to add a custom icon with the ripple effect.

Comment: not a good answer. this way you can add ripple to the icon, but not the title + icon as a whole